# How does a spinning hard drive handle the flipping of a computer?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron

I have a computer that has a base screen that can be flipped basically 360°. But I get worried about flipping it, while the computer is running, since I've heard of possibly damaging the hard drive, if the disc hits the head. How does the computer, that can flip its screen, not get damaged or do they? Would flipping my screen cause any problems?

Comment: probably has an SSD drive which has no spinning disk but acts like one.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember is the hard drive is typically in the base of the computer, so it's not the part being flipped.

Another is that drives are normally parked when powered off, so they are a lot less likely to get damaged if the drive is not spinning.

Generally drives can take a fair bit of movement - when you drop a drive it's the sudden impact/deceleration and resulting vibration that do the damage.